# Form Recognizer

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I generated the Model Id using From Recognizer Labeling too (The docker image).
I am trying to use this same model id in From Recognizer API.

https://{endpoint}/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/models/{id}

but it say 404 .

https://centralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api/operations/GetCustomModel

The below URL says we can use the generated model Id:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool

**Model ID - The ID of the model that was created and trained. Each training call creates a new model with its own ID. Copy this string to a secure location; you'll need it if you want to do prediction calls through the REST API.**

Answer (score 2):

I have recently tried the form-recognizer API. Please use the below URL and test it in the Postman first.

https://{{endpoint}}/formrecognizer/v2.0-preview/custom/models/{{modelId}}

Replace endpoint  and modelId with  {{name of your form-recognizer-service}}.cognitiveservices.azure.com and your modelId  respectively. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I did same but returned response is 404 .
Actually to generated the model Id ,
I used the labeling tool mention in below URL
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool

And I am trying to use the model ID in the below API
https://{{endpoint}}/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/models/{{modelId}}

Comment: More precise question would be "can we used model Id generated using Labeling tool in API(https://{endpoint}/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/models/{id}) ?".

Comment: The labeling tool should only work with v2.0-preview. Have you tried https://{endpoint}/formrecognizer/v2.0-preview/custom/models/{id})

Comment: Yes, I too checked. Please use the V2.0 in API Url. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

When generating models using the Form Recognizer sample labeling tool you are generating Form Recognizer v2.0 (preview) models. To get those models status or analyze forms with those models please use the Form Recognizer v2.0-preivew API https://aka.ms/form-recognizer/api .